# WebDav to EWS (contact)

Tags: .net, vb.net, exchangewebservices

I'm converting an application from using **WebDav** to **EWS**. I'm now in the process on converting the code the fetch contact.

I notice that the property from **WebDav** were found by using

`urn:schemas:contacts:facsimiletelephonenumber`
`urn:schemas:contacts:fileas`
...

And the property of **EWS** are "normal" like

`_contact.PhoneNumbers(PhoneNumberKey.HomeFax)`
`_contact.FileAs`

Does anyone know if there's a list that could help me convert
`urn:schemas:contacts:fileas` -> `_contact.FileAs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no list for **WebDav** to **EWS** conversions, you would have to map them yourself. Here is the [WebDav schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa123736%28v=exchg.65%29.aspx) and [EWS Contact properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg274394.aspx#PropertyIdValues) for reference. It should be self-explanatory how to map them as they are named quite similarly.